# How to read Cloudfront headers in Spartacus

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-cloudfront, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

`Hi,
 We are trying to setup AWS Cloudfront as the CDN for Spartacus Hybis Storefront and would like to extract the Cloudfront Header value for the key 'cloudfront-viewer-postal-code' to get the user's postcode for store finder. At this stage, the HttpInterceptor is not getting the value from the request header. In the past, we have successfully extracted this value in the accstorefront. Not sure what is getting missed in the Jsstorefront which is enabled for SSR

Below is the code snippet when we try to print the request header which does not print 'cloudfront-viewer-postal-code' as one of the header key

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor { intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 
      const yourHeaderKeys = req.headers.keys() 
      console.log('Headers', yourHeaderKeys);
      return next.handle(req); } `
```

We have just used standard AWS policy guidelines to pass the headers as follows to the origin

"cloudfront-viewer-country-region": |
"key: "CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region",
"value: "NSW"
"cloudfront-viewer-postal-code":
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Postal-Code",
"value: "2000"
"cloudfront-viewer-latitude":
"key: "CloudFront-Viewer-Latitude",
"value: "-33.87150"
"cloudfront-viewer-longitude":
| "key: "CloudFront-Viewer-Longitude"
"value": –

Able to read the above in the Accstorefront but not in JSStorefront.

Comment: Can you share more details on how your origin requests policy is set and what headers you are forwarding to the origin?

Comment: We have just used standard AWS guidelines to pass the headers as follows to the origin"cloudfront-viever-country":
"key:
"value:
"CloudFront-Viewer-Country",
"cloudfront-viewer-country-region": |
"key:
"CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region",
"value:
"NSW"
"cloudfront-viewer-postal-code":
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Postal-Code",
"value:
"2000"
"cloudfront-viewer-latitude":
"key:
"CloudFront-Viewer-Latitude",
"value:
"-33.87150"
"cloudfront-viewer-longitude": |
"key:
"CloudFront-Viewer-Longitude"
"value":

Comment: Can you share screenshots to show cloudfront cache policy configuration